# Dynamics AX --> BizTalk incomplete message with new AIF-Service

Tags: biztalk, ax, aif

i've got a little Problem regarding the AIF-Service in Dynamics Ax when sending a production order to BizTalk:

I'v made a query (AxdProdTest) for the ProdTable including the ProdId, ItemId and ProdType as fields and the ProdJournalTable as sub datasource including ProdId, JournalId and JournalType as fields. (1:n, Outer Join)

For this query i have created an AIF-Servic using the wizard as described in the walktrough.

Now i've got a production order with one picklist and one routecard. When i send this using the AIF-Service i get the XML-Message having the desired information from the ProdTable but only one entry from the ProdJournalTable (picklist) although there are two of them.

What do i have to change when i have a 1:n connection in the query and need the same in my outgoing XML? There must be a way because it works with the standard services as SalesOrder or Invoices

Thx for your Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are the table joins defined in your query? I've seen the behavior you described when using the default of InnerJoin, but I get the expected 1:n behavior when using OuterJoin.